# Need help -> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

I have a website and when I am trying to create new content and choose a category I have an error. Did you happend to have this issue before?

I dont know to resolve this.

```
     setHierarchyPaths: function (categories, path) {
        for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
            if (typeof path !== 'undefined') {
                categories[i].path = path + '.' + categories[i].id;
            } else {
                categories[i].path = categories[i].id;
            }

            if (categories[i].childrens.length > 0) {
                this.setHierarchyPaths(categories[i].childrens, 
      categories[i].path);
            }

            // We need a flat tree!
            this.flatTree.push(categories[i]);
        }
    },
```

I have uploaded the error on these 2 pictures. Hope you can help me with this.
https://www.screencast.com/t/PWjbxIgJe

https://www.screencast.com/t/Jt2RN08G

Many thanks

Comment: Either `categories` or `categories[i].childrens` is `undefined`. Please give a [mcve].

Comment: How do you call `setHierarchyPaths`?

Answer (score 1):

This is a quite common kind of error. It happens when you try to access the attribute (or method) of an object that does not exist.

An example

```
const myObject: SomeObject;
if ( myObject.length === 0) {... }
```

In this case `myObjec` is declared but still undefined.
So, as a result, the `length` attribute is called on undefined. And you will get the error "cannot read property length of undefined".

In your case, please check how the method `setHierarchyPaths` is called, because it seems (as jonrsharpe already said in the comment), that the parameter `categories` was provided with an undefined value.